# Merging overlaying rasters into one using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, merge

How do I merge black and white rasters into one file using QGIS?

Also, rasters are overlaying so I´m interested into preserving only black colour.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  At the moment you question is a little limited. A simple answer would be in QGIS you would use the 'Raster > Raster Calculator' to merge two layers together.  Understand that the colour of the cells is only a representation that QGIS makes for a value.  Could you update your question to include what values it is you are trying to preserve/using.  EG. if black = 1 and white = 0, then you would simple add the two layers together. Check this link out learn more about the calculator:    https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_calculator.html

Comment: Thank you for you answer! Values I would like to preserve is as you described; 1= black and 0=white. I tried to add it but nothing came out as result...

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

To add two rasters together, whilst preserving a value, as long as raster cell values are 1 or 0 is to multiply them in the raster calculator.

```
"raster1" * "raster2"
```

Multiplication works because: 1*1 = 1  and 1*0 = 0

Set the raster calculator to output the same crs as both your other layers, otherwise you could create a raster that ends up in a different location.

Comment: What if black should be preserved if either a or b has black pixels, or both?

Comment: Not sure what you're fully asking. hypothetically, wouldn't a raster have all those examples/variations you suggested?  this isn't my particular expertise but would you not try using a polygon to clip a particular area you wish to preserve. Or have I completely missed the point here.

Comment: If raster 1 has a line, let's say road, it has black pixels where the road is located. If raster 2 overlaps but does not contain that road I suppose that the resulting merged raster should have ones, not zeros because black=1? With your formula it would be white (0 * 1=0). But I do not know what is the aim of the exercise and I am just guessing. Perhaps a simple image merging by defining 0 as a nodata leads to good result.

Comment: That's a good explanation.  Using addition would certainly fix that problem, but would then also introduce a lot of new values, which would change the data.  Just looked at the merge tool and your right, that would probably be best if zero was nodata.

Comment: Can you take max((raster1),(raster2)) with raster calculator?

Comment: Not with the expression written like that it doesn't work in QGIS.  Like I said working with rasters is not something I'm well versed in, I just know some basic stuff.  But having a google of max (I think it selects the max cell values of the raster) it would effectively ignore 0 cells doing a similar job as merge with nodata...I assume

Answer (score 1):

So as user30184 wrote - roads needs to be preserved (0*1=0) and this is wrong solution. I managed to solve the problem in GRASS GIS. I don't think it is possible to solve it in QGIS.

Merge tool don´t work since rasters overlap (white area than covers black).