# Is it possible to merge DEM rasters on top of each other instead of side by side?

Tags: raster, qgis-3

Is it possible to merge a smaller raster with a larger raster underneath, where the smaller raster is a subset of the larger one?  The rasters are all created from LPC point cloud data.

Say you have a base DEM in one layer, and in the layer above it you have a specific feature from that base raster that was created with the same CRS but with a different resolution and IDW settings.

The use case for that would be to vary the settings to allow the smaller raster to have more details, without having to process the entire base raster at a high detail, which takes an incredible amount of time.

Comment: You can merge rasters in many different ways, but the spatial resolution has to be the same for both datasets. Can you tile the DEM and iteratively process the individual tiles?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merging overlaying rasters into one using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216274/merging-overlaying-rasters-into-one-using-qgis)